# How to find modem IP by using Boost::Asio

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to get my modem's IPv4 address by using Boost::Asio and C++. For doing this, I try this code:

```cpp
try {
    boost::asio::io_service netService;
    udp::resolver resolver(netService);
    udp::resolver::query query(udp::v4(), "google.com", "");
    udp::resolver::iterator endpoints = resolver.resolve(query);
    udp::endpoint ep = *endpoints;
    udp::socket socket(netService);
    socket.connect(ep);
    boost::asio::ip::address addr = socket.local_endpoint().address();
    std::cout << "My IP according to google is: " << addr.to_string() << std::endl;
} 
catch (std::exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << "Could not deal with socket. Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

But, what this code shows me is the Interface IP, for example:

`192.168.1.100`

But when I try it with IPv6, it works correctly.

My question is, **why** is this happening, and how can I get the correct IP?

Comment: 192.168.1.100 is your IP, the router that give you access to "external" internet has another "public" IP, but that IP is not accessible to your device, like all the others intermediate routers IPs to your destination (just think about it, you could have several gateways). Should you try the same approach than `tracert` command? that is, to send UDP packet with TTL 1 and see who reply.

Comment: so how can I get IP that [this site](https://www.ipify.org) show me? I want this IP.

Comment: That site has the benefit to be on the other side of the request. You could have a server giving your your public IP for that request.

Comment: Is there any way that I get IP from that Site by using c++ and boost?

Comment: @Parisa.H.R You would have to send an HTTPS `GET` request over TCP to `https://api.ipify.org`, and then read the response back, just like a web browser would. See [Simple HTTP Client](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/quick_start/http_client.html) in Boost::Asio's documentation for an example.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding to me. I will try this.